# how to handle Broadcast created inside Activity ?

Tags: android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver

i was created a BroadcastReceiver inside `Activity` (`ActionBarActivity`)

like this

---

```
public class MyTabListner extends ActionBarActivity {
.
.
.

    public class AppManagerBroadcast extends BroadcastReceiver {

                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                    boolean applicationStatus = intent.getBooleanExtra(Intent.EXTRA_REPLACING, false);
                    String toastMessage = null;
                    if(intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.PACKAGE_INSTALL")){
                        toastMessage = "PACKAGE_INSTALL: "+  intent.getData().toString();


                    }else
                    if(intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED")){
                        toastMessage = "PACKAGE_REPLACED: "+  intent.getData().toString() ;

                    }else
                    if(intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED")){
                        toastMessage = "PACKAGE_REMOVED: "+  intent.getData().toString();

                    }
                    //Display Toast Message
                    if(toastMessage != null){
                        Toast.makeText(context, toastMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }



            }
.
.
.
}
```

---

I register in manifest.xml 
like this

```
 <receiver
            android:name="com.example.activity.MyTabListner$AppManagerBroadcast"
            android:enabled="true" >
            <intent-filter android:priority="1" >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_INSTALL" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED" />
                <data android:scheme="package" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

but i got exception in this way .
exception is .

```
09-11 17:45:46.434: E/AndroidRuntime(23502): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-11 17:45:46.434: E/AndroidRuntime(23502): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver com.example.activity.MyTabListner$AppManagerBroadcast: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class com.example.activity.MyTabListner$AppManagerBroadcast; no empty constructor

09-11 17:45:46.434: E/AndroidRuntime(23502): Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class com.example.activity.MyTabListner$AppManagerBroadcast; no empty constructor
```

when i created out side activity then i am sucess fully run my app but
i want to use this **broadcastreceiver** in my **Activity** **not outside activity**.
how to avoid this exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inner class must be an static class.

Change

```
public class AppManagerBroadcast extends BroadcastReceiver
```

to

```
public static class AppManagerBroadcast extends BroadcastReceiver
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me you have to declare your inner class as static. Currently the inner class has to be used with instance of the outer class, which might not be what you want.